# Uploading files on Server

Tags: php

I am writing an app from which user will upload files on the server. I have found a php script from internet but I don't know how am I going to tell the script where to upload the data. This might be a silly question but I am no PHP programmer. I am using this php script in my java code.

Here is the script.

```
<?php
  $filename="abc.xyz";
  $fileData=file_get_contents('php://input');
  echo("Done uploading");
?>
```

Regards

Comment: See the documentation of $_FILE on PHP Manual, there are many examples for this.

Comment: What do you mean you are using a php script in your java code? What are you actually trying to accomplish here, are you trying to upload a file from the user's browser to the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filename is actualy the file path along with the name of the new file, set the path there and a file will be created with write permissions.

Make sure you give the servers full path not the relative one and that you have the required permission to create a file there.

Comment: Hey bro how can I change the download link of the file, I mean at the moment the download link is the same as upload link, which means any one can hack into my server. So is there a way to change the download address.

Comment: You can make a php script that fetches the upload from a different link as well as uploading the file then moving it somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

This is a terrible way of uploading files, you are much better off using a form and the `$_FILES` superglobal.

Take a look at the [W3Schools PHP File Upload Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp); please read all of it. For further reading take a look at the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php) pages on file upload.

The `file` input type will create the upload box in the html form:

```
<form action="upload_file.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="file">Filename:</label>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

After error checking and validating that the file is what you are expecting (very important: allowing users to upload *anything* to your server is a huge security risk), you can move the uploaded file to your final destination on the server in PHP.

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "upload/abc.xyz");
```

Answer (score 0):

Always refer to the [PHP Manual](http://php.net)

Here's a basic example to get you started:

**HTML:**

```
<html> 
<body>
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1000000" />
    Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploaded_file" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
  </form> 
</body> 
</html>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
//Сheck that we have a file
if((!empty($_FILES["uploaded_file"])) && ($_FILES['uploaded_file']['error'] == 0)) {
  //Check if the file is JPEG image and it's size is less than 350Kb
  $filename = basename($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
  $ext = substr($filename, strrpos($filename, '.') + 1);
  if (($ext == "jpg") && ($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") && 
    ($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["size"] < 350000)) {
    //Determine the path to which we want to save this file
      $newname = dirname(__FILE__).'/upload/'.$filename;
      //Check if the file with the same name is already exists on the server
      if (!file_exists($newname)) {
        //Attempt to move the uploaded file to it's new place
        if ((move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'],$newname))) {
           echo "It's done! The file has been saved as: ".$newname;
        } else {
           echo "Error: A problem occurred during file upload!";
        }
      } else {
         echo "Error: File ".$_FILES["uploaded_file"]["name"]." already exists";
      }
  } else {
     echo "Error: Only .jpg images under 350Kb are accepted for upload";
  }
} else {
 echo "Error: No file uploaded";
}
?>
```

Refer to the [documention](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php) for more information.

Hope this helps!